# How/Where to insert <br/> tag in the middle of a javascript string literal?

Tags: html, angularjs

Using angular.js, I'm trying to print the phrase "Hello World!" in the code below as two lines, i.e.

`Hello
World!`

I'm not sure where to insert the `<br/>` tag to do this. I've tried the following without success:

`$scope.test = "Hello <br/> World!"`

`$scope.test = "Hello" + <br/> + "World!"`

Below is the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
            <span ng-bind="test"></span>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module("app", []);

            app.controller("controller", function($scope){
                $scope.test = "Hello World!";
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security reason, angular would print HTML tags directly if it is used in binding value.

You can use `ng-bind-html` for this purpose after including the `ngSanitize` module and inject `$sanitize` service in your controller/directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: Do you happen to know how to write the code if I want to use the `{{.....}}` instead of `ng-bind-html`? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is way, at least an easy way for that. Is there any specific reason to do that other than cosmetic purpose?

Comment: It's for the ease of writing codes and formatting what's displayed on the page. I'm trying to add some formatting (e.g. `<br>`, `<b>`) in either `{{...}}` or `ng-bind-html` inside an `ng-repeat` (rows in a table). If I use the brackets form `{{}}`, I could add the html tags right before or after it; otherwise, I would have to jump back and forth between the html and the script to do the formatting.

Comment: How about writing a full snippet in a `.html` and use `ng-include` instead?

Comment: Yeah I can do that. Just started learning angular.js so I was exploring different options.

Answer (score 0):

Icycool's answer is a superb way to deal with the issue.

I've also figured out a simple solution for my question (might not work for general cases though). If you wrap the binding value with the `<pre>` tag, any formatting of the string literal will be preserved.

Comment: Can you give example on how to wrap in tag? Thanks.

Comment: @Icycool I've just edited my answer. I meant to say to use the `<pre>` tag but forgot to put it in the ` `, so the tag didn't appear in my answer. My apologies for this!